# Ants are stealing our picnic!

Tags: animation, trope

So we often see scenes in cartoons in which a nice picnic is laid out with all sorts of tasty food, and all of a sudden, we see half a sandwich moving away, followed by a banana, then the other half of the sandwich, etc.

**What made this trope of ants stealing picnics so popular?**

The earliest animation I could find was [Ants at the Picnic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWhZ6dxSpwI) (1930) by Disney.

Comment: *"What made this notion of ants stealing picnics so popular?"* Er, real life? ;)

Comment: @Walt, you must have big-ass ants where you live if each one can walk away with a sandwich :-)

Comment: Nah, [the opposite!](http://img.ifcdn.com/images/2dc50c77eff82b969847f7aa25950f3d43bbf6c284ba9fe6d17944a1532845a4_1.jpg) ;)

Comment: @Walt, can I just say you have very pretty fingernails ;-)

Comment: One? No, many. http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/07/29/16/2AEFAC4600000578-3178761-The_researchers_found_that_the_ants_have_a_finely_tuned_system_t-a-6_1438182237228.jpg

Comment: I mean... it's pretty common to exaggerate real-life occurrences for comic effect. (Where do you think satire comes from?) And as @Walt pointed out, real-life ants are known for going after people's food, even if they aren't generally big enough to carry off entire sandwiches on their own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**General Idea about Ants:**

Ants can eat a wide variety of foods. They eat plants, other insects and sometimes steal food from other insects. They also like sweets, which explains why they're more than happy to invade a picnic that showed up in their area.

**In cartoons/films:**

**This ant-stealing-our-picnic has its comic aspect (as shown in movies/tv shows)** which is a reason behind its popularity. In many shows, you probably see that leading character(s) goes/go to ant's area (or nearby area) and they steal foods and carry these to their home. This scene is depicted in a comedy way to make viewer laugh and it worked out.

Stealing food might be their way of saying that you decided to have a picnic on our turf and now you will pay.

In some species, there is a forager who finds foods when finished. When food is laid out on a picnic, smell of nice food, which is of course, makes them come out and steal it.